# Is it necessary to calculate crc32 when writing zip files?

Tags: zip

I'm designing my own tiny zip writer and RAM is pretty limited.
I'm also not using any compression...

So I'm wonder:

- Is it possible to create a zip file that do not contain any crc32 checksums in either the entry header or the central directory and have it still be a valid zip file? is crc32 optional or a requirement?
- can i set some flag to something to indicate that it dose not have crc32 checksum and set the crc bits to just 1 or 0?

I just want to avoid having to read each file and calculate the checksum and simply just do a kind of concatenation of multiple files

Comment: Have you consider using `tar`? It looks for me this is what you want.

Comment: No. If you want a zip file that will work with all the standard unzip utilities it must have a valid crc.